# __getattr__ method in python

Tags: python, oop, delegates

i meet this code today, and it seems confusing

```
class ClassOne:
    def __init__(self,some_object):
        self.not_important_attribute=some_object   
class ClassTwo:
    def __init__(self,some_object):
        self.tmp=ClassOne(some_object)
    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        return getattr(self.tmp,attr)
a=ClassTwo('not_important_string')
print(getattr(a,'undefined_attribute',3))
```

When we use `getattr` at the last line we trigger the `__getattr__` method in the `SubClass` , then delegate to the `getattr(self.tmp,attr)` function which will raise an exception if the attribute is undefined and no default value was given. But how the value 3 at the last line still go through all the process, and eventually return to `getattr(a,'undefined_attribute',3)` function ?. Because we didn't have a slot for the default value when we delegate `getattr(self.tmp,attr)`, how is that possible ?

Comment: Yeah,  it's not a inheritance mechanism, i will edit that

Comment: If \__getattr__ raises AttributeError then function getattr return default value if exist (in your case is 3).

Comment: @AndreyBerenda I'm not sure that's correct, when method `__getattr__` is called, it'll return the value we defined it inside the function, not the default value outside the class, check [this](https://onlinegdb.com/SkGMTaMfH)

Answer (score 2):

In your case

```
getattr(self.tmp,attr)
```

raises AttributeError and if getattr has third argument(default value) then it return default value instead of raising AttributeError

Comment: "if getattr has third argument"
Which getattr you're talking about, the `getattr(self.tmp,attr)` or the `getattr(a,'undefined_attribute',3)` outside the class.

Comment: @TuấnĐoàn both are calling at attribute `not_important_attribute` of class `ClassOne`, look at my answer for more details

Comment: I am talking about getattr(a,'undefined_attribute',3). getattr(self.tmp,attr) raises AttributeError and getattr(a,'undefined_attribute',3) returns 3 because of default value

Comment: @AndreyBerenda when method `__getattr__` is called, it'll return the value we defined it inside the function, not the default value outside the class, check [this](https://www.onlinegdb.com/SkGMTaMfH)

Comment: I am talking about the case print(getattr(b,'undefined_attribute',3))

Answer (score 1):

Step by step why `3` value is shown:

> the super class has has an atribute `not_important_attribute` and it is set when the constructor is called

```
class ClassOne:
    def __init__(self,some_object):
        self.not_important_attribute=some_object
```

> Here, in the `ClassTwo` contructor, you create an instance of `ClassOne` and save it into `tmp` variable. Meaning that when you overrides `__getattr__` you will be asking for the value of attribute of `ClassOne`

```
print(getattr(a,'not_important_attribute',3))
not_important_string # founds the method
print(getattr(a,'any',3))
3 #doesn't found method, returns default
```

That is the same of directly do:

```
b = ClassOne("not_important_string")
print(getattr(b,'not_important_attribute',3))
not_important_string # founds the method
print(getattr(b,'any',3))
3 # doesn't found method, returns default
```

Answer (score 0):

When calling `getattr(a,'undefined_attribute',3)` you are calling the standard python getattr function and pass it a default value. This actually wraps your custom **getattr** in ClassTwo. We can see that by modifying **getattr** al little bit.

```
   def __getattr__(self, attr, *args, **kwargs):
        print(args)  # -> empty
        print(kwargs)  # -> empty
        return getattr(self.tmp, attr)
```

You can actually go around that wrapping and call **getattr** from ClassTwo directly, by using `print(a.__getattr__('undefined_attribute', 3))`. This method would raise an Exception.

So essentially `getattr(a,'undefined_attribute',3)` is the standard python method that internally calls the custom getattr from ClassTwo.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ClassTwo:
...
    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        return getattr(self.tmp,attr)
```

`getattr(a,'undefined_attribute',3)` method is a wrapper to call `__getattribute__` and if `__getattribute__` fails, it will call `__getattr__`. It is implemented with handling of exception `AttributeError`. In your case, `getattr(a,'undefined_attribute',3)` calls `ClassTwo.__getattr__` above.

It seems you think  when it reaches `return getattr(self.tmp,attr)`, it will throw errors or return some kind of errors and break and stop at that point complete. However, in python, program will pass exception up the call stack. Along the upstream of the call stack, if that exception gets handle, it will exit/complete normally. In this case, `AttributeError` get passed back along the call stack to `getattr(a,'undefined_attribute',3)`. this `getattr` has default value for `AttributeError` so it returns `3` and exits normally.